# Template naming

Tags: c++, templates

I have a question about template naming, e.g.

```
template ＜typename T, typename U＞
class Something {...};
```

What does `[U]` mean?
`[T]` is maybe "Template"
`[U]` is what...?

I thought it's alphabet order: `...T U V W X Y Z`?

Comment: You can make up whatever names you want. They are just place-holders.

Comment: They are just names, like variable names.  It could just as easily be `template <typename dog, typename cat>`.

Comment: 'T' is type, 'U' next in alphabet, but this is just a convention

Comment: Since it's an arbitrary type parameter of class template, people would often name it `T` (for "Type", or so I have always assumed). Sometimes the names convey meaning, as in `template <typename Iterator> void copy(Iterator first, Iterator last);`, for example. Or `template <typename Key, typename Value> class map;`, etc.

Comment: I always learned its best to have template type names be single, capital letters to distinguish them from other names in the program. There's also `E` for element, `V` for value, etc. Mostly abbreviations. Like using `K` and `V` in a map for key and value, respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no specific reason for that. Its just an **arbitrary alphabet token** taken. Yes you can say that it is taken in alphabetical order. No other reason.

Different programmers have different patterns like if its a single template parameter, then I also take it as T(U,V..etc). But when it is a multiple template parameter I prefer to give a descriptive name(*but this all is a matter of style*)